# iOS build pipeline taking more than 50 minutes

Tags: ios, react-native, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've Created below YAML for iOS Build Pipeline for Monorepo environment and  Reactive as frontend. Pipeline is taking so much of time (Nearly 57 minutes) in Azure Devops, specially build step taking 39-43 minutes. Please help to reduce the pipeline build time.

```
trigger:
    - none
  resources:
    - repo: self
  pool:
    vmImage: 'macos-latest'
  variables:
    - group: resfebervariables   #Variable name where certificate password has been saved.
  steps:
    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: true
      clean: true
    - task: NodeTool@0
      displayName: 'Install Node'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '18.0.0' # you can use your desired version here
    - script: yarn install
      displayName: Install Dependencies
    - script: |
        # Disable autocommit on version bump 
        yarn config set version-sign-git-tag false
        yarn config set version-git-tag false
        yarn config set version-commit-hooks false
        # Checkout branch where the build is triggered
        git checkout $(Build.SourceBranchName)
        # Extract existing version of package.json
        oldVer=$(jq -r ".version" package.json)
        # Bump version
        yarn version --patch
        # Add bumped version to staging
        git add *
        # Extract new version of package.json
        newVer=$(jq -r ".version" package.json)
        # Set environment variables
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=OLD_VERSION]$oldVer"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NEW_VERSION]$newVer"
      displayName: 'Bump version and set variables'
    - task: ios-bundle-version@1
      displayName: 'Bump iOS version'
      inputs:
        sourcePath: 'packages/res-feber-mobile/ios/resfebermobile/Info.plist'
        versionCodeOption: 'buildid'
        versionCode: '$(Build.BuildId)'
        versionName: '$(NEW_VERSION)'
        printFile: false
    - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
      displayName: Install Apple Certificate
      inputs:
        certSecureFile: 'resfeber.p12'
        certPwd: '$(p12password)'
        keychain: 'temp'
        deleteCert: true
    - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
      displayName: 'Install Apple Provisioning Profile'
      inputs:
        provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
        provProfileSecureFile: 'resfeber_Enterprise_QA.mobileprovision'
        removeProfile: true
    - task: CocoaPods@0
      displayName: 'Install CocoaPods'
      inputs:
        workingDirectory: '/Users/runner/work/1/s/packages/res-feber-mobile/ios'
    - task: Xcode@5
      displayName: 'Build IPA'
      inputs:
        actions: 'build'
        configuration: 'Qa'
        sdk: 'iphoneos'
        scheme: 'resfebermobileQa'
        xcWorkspacePath: '/Users/runner/work/1/s/packages/res-feber-mobile/ios/resfebermobile.xcworkspace'
        packageApp: true
        exportPath: 'output/$(SDK)/$(Configuration)'
        exportMethod: 'enterprise'
        signingOption: 'manual'
        signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
        provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
        Contents: |
          **/*.ipa
          **/*.dSYM/**
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        overWrite: true
        cleanTargetFolder: true
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: iOSBuild'
      inputs:
        ArtifactName: iOSBuild
```

help needed to reduce the build time.
yarn install function can be used script can be commented.
[Pipeline steps and timing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpbgw.png)

Answer (score 1):

I am able to extend my pipeline time duration for Azure Hosted Agent, I've added 1 job at pipeline root lable with timeout and added time out in each tasks.

```
trigger:
  - none
resources:
  - repo: self
variables:
  - group: resfebervariables
jobs:
  - job: build
    timeoutInMinutes: 180
    pool:
      vmImage: 'macos-latest'
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: true
      clean: true
    - task: NodeTool@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Install Node'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '18.8.0' # you can use your desired version here
    - script: yarn install
      displayName: Install Dependencies
    - script: |
        # Disable autocommit on version bump 
        yarn config set version-sign-git-tag false
        yarn config set version-git-tag false
        yarn config set version-commit-hooks false
        Checkout branch where the build is triggered
        git checkout $(Build.SourceBranchName)
        # Extract existing version of package.json
        oldVer=$(jq -r ".version" package.json)
        # Bump version
        yarn version --patch
        # Add bumped version to staging
        git add *
        # Extract new version of package.json
        newVer=$(jq -r ".version" package.json)
        # Set environment variables
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=OLD_VERSION]$oldVer"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NEW_VERSION]$newVer"
      displayName: 'Bump version and set variables'
    - task: ios-bundle-version@1
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Bump iOS version'
      inputs:
        sourcePath: 'packages/res-feber-mobile/ios/resfebermobile/Info.plist'
        # versionCodeOption: 'buildid'
        versionCode: '$(VERSION_CODE)'
        versionName: '$(VERSION_NAME)'
        printFile: false
    - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: Install Apple Certificate
      inputs:
        certSecureFile: 'resfeber.p12'
        certPwd: '$(p12password)'
        keychain: 'temp'
        deleteCert: true
    - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Install Apple Provisioning Profile'
      inputs:
        provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
        provProfileSecureFile: 'resfeber.mobileprovision'
        removeProfile: true
    - task: CocoaPods@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Install CocoaPods'
      inputs:
        workingDirectory: '/Users/runner/work/1/s/packages/res-feber-mobile/ios'
    - task: Xcode@5
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Build IPA'
      inputs:
        actions: 'build'
        configuration: 'Qa'
        sdk: 'iphoneos'
        scheme: 'resfebermobileQa'
        xcWorkspacePath: '/Users/runner/work/1/s/packages/res-feber-mobile/ios/resfebermobile.xcworkspace'
        packageApp: true
        exportPath: 'output/$(SDK)/$(Configuration)'
        exportMethod: 'enterprise'
        signingOption: 'manual'
        signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
        provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
        Contents: |
          **/*.ipa
          **/*.dSYM/**
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        overWrite: true
        cleanTargetFolder: true
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: iOSBuild'
      inputs:
        ArtifactName: iOSBuild
```

Comment: Did you change agent type? How adding timeout reduced your build time?